# Start activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-annotations, start-activity

i'm trying to start an activity which is in a MaterielDialog and this one is in a Fragment.

Here is my Fragment part :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SubjectViewActivity_.class);
i.putExtra("subject", projects.getFileurl());
startActivity(i);
```

And in SubjectViewActivity :

```
@UiThread
void setSubject(String LinkTo) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LinkTo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(LinkTo);
    setContentView(webview);
}

@AfterViews
void init() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getExtras().getString("subject");
    setSubject(url);
}
```

I get this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I'm using the android annotation. I've tryed many issues on stack but no one works.

Thanks by advance

Comment: The problem is in the startActivity or in the second activity's load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you set content view before setContentView in `void setSubject(String LinkTo)` call? If you do you do not need to set it again.

It looks like you already have the webview in your Activity's layout.

Comment: Do you set the contentView before setSubject? Like in onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback. Implement an interface within the fragment suchas:

```
public interface OnChangeActivityListener{
    void changeActivity()
}
```

And then in your activity implement the interface. Within the `changeActivity()` method implement your creation of the new intent. Intent and Activity management should happen at the Activity level, not at the Fragment level.

more info: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html